# I cannot detect(monitoring) Ibeacon with using AltbeaconLibrary in Android

Tags: android, monitoring, detection, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I have an android application. My purpose is detect Ibeacons with using AltBeacon library. I used **Monitoring Example Code** from AltBeacon Library Site Link: (http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html). But I cannot detect any Ibeacon. And cannot get any log about detection of any beacon.

My Manifest File is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ibeaconscanner.ibeaconproject.ibeaconproject" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I added **Requesting Permission** codes to MainActivity.java to solve problem but couldn't.
My MainActivity.java like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {
    protected static final String TAG = "MyApp";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("This app needs location acces");
                builder.setMessage("Please grat location acces so this app can detect beacons");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                Log.d(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");
            }

            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                Log.d(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
                Log.d(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: " + state);
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "coarse location permission granted");
                } else {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                    builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons when in the background.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

                        }
                    }
                    );
                    builder.show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect iBeacons, you will need to modify the altbeacon library to make it understand the ibeacon packet format. Try this in onCreate function :

```
beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
        beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1000l);
        beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(10000l);
        beaconManager.bind(this);
```

1. setBeaconLayout defines the packet structure for detecting iBeacons. You can learn more about the packet structure [here](http://www.warski.org/blog/2014/01/how-ibeacons-work/).
2. setForegroundScanPeriod is set as 1 second and setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod is set as 10 seconds in my code. You can change this to any value you want. You may probably want to reduce setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod to say 3 seconds depending on your need. Basically, these two settings define that the device be in scan mode for 1 second, and repeat scanning every 10 seconds.

**UPDATE**

To display UUIDs of detected beacons, use the following :

```
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                 for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {   
                      logToDisplay("Detected " + beacon.toString() + " with UUID " + beacon.getId1().toString() + " and Major ID " + beacon.getId2().toString() + " and Minor ID " + beacon.getId3().toString()); 
                }
            }
            else {
                logToDisplay("No iBeacons detected");
            }
        }

    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(myRegion);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {   }

}

private void logToDisplay(final String line) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            EditText editText = (EditText)RangingActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.rangingText);
            editText.append(line+"\n");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, how can I handle which beacon(UUID) is detected ? I guess that  need to use didEnterRegion(),didDetermineStateForRegion(), didExitRegion() function to handle Ibeacons. But these function parameters doesn't give any information about Ibeacon.

Comment: How can I any operation in these functions( didDetermineStateForRegion() etc.) above ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to display UUIDs of detected beacons.

Comment: Okey.I was changed code like yours above. But I cannot any operation in didRangeBeaconsInRegion() function. For example: I want to list all beacons detected on screen. How can I do it ?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question. My updated code exactly does that - list detected beacons on the screen. The for loop calls logToDisplay function - you will need to define a view with edit text ID as given in my code. Let me know if you're facing any issues in getting the view setup.

Answer (score 1):

A few tips:

1. Make sure you can detect your beacon with an off-the-shelf beacon detection app like [Locate.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en)  If you can't see the beacon, then there may be a hardware problem.
2. By default, the library only detects beacons sending the AltBeacon format.  If you are using a proprietary beacon type, you'll need to call `beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("**PUT LAYOUT EXPRESSION HERE**"));` to add the layout for your beacon type.
3. If you are on Android 6, make sure that your app has granted location permissions.  Go to Settings -> Apps -> [Your app name] -> Permissions, and make sure location permissions are granted.
4. If you are on Android 6, check to see that Settings -> Location is set to On.  This is necessary for some devices including the Nexus 5.
5. If the above doesn't help, try adding logging to your app (like in  `onBeaconServiceConnect()`) and report back which methods get called and which do not.